# Uploading products from multiple accounts simultaneously in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to upload and update products from multiple accounts at once. Is it safe to do so? I am using Magento 2.3.4

Comment: What do you mean multiple accounts? it it a multi vendor marketplace? if yes, it is possible. You just need to upload products (admin>system>import) and assign products to each vendor afterwards login into their accounts

Comment: @MarconyMonteiro No, its not a multi vendor marketplace. It has a single store and we have lot of products to upload. So, I was wondering if I a made multiple backend accounts with necessary permission. And then multiple people, using different devices could log in backend and upload products simultaneously. Hope I am able to explain my question clearly this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following.

Navigate on admin > system > Permissions > User Roles

Then, create a role with the permissions you want checking the boxes. As adding product by importing or edit catalog product, as in the example below:

Please note that the best way for mass upload is by importing the .csv file, not product by product. But do as per your best convenience.

Hope that helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, my question is, will it cause any problems, if say, 10 people ,each using a different account logs in the backend at same time and all of them add products.

Comment: I see no problem for simultaneous connections to your admin account. If you face issues, you just need to make sure your MySQL is properly configured to allow this number of users. Please follow the oficial document here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html

Comment: okay, Thanks for clearing it up.